# Where should I place my chromedriver file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, selenium, path, environment-variables

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. I have a Rails app "project" located at `home/user/project`. I want to use [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) with SeleniumWebdriver. I downloaded the ChromeDriver executable, but Selenium can't find the file. It gives me this error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: Unable to find the chromedriver executable.
Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH
```

I've spent upwards of an hour reading articles/questions about PATH and environmental variables, and they keep talking about editing files like ~/.profile and ~/.bashrc and ~/.pam_environment, but from what I can tell my computer doesn't even have any of those files.

Isn't there just some folder where I can place the ChromeDriver executable so that Selenium can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the file in `/home/user/project` and add `PATH=/home/user/project:$PATH` to your `~/.bashrc` file. If it doesn't exist, create it.

Comment: Should `~/.bashrc`, if it exists, just be in my home/user folder?

Comment: It should exist in your home folder. Just type `gedit ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Oh okay I guess it does exist! So anywhere in the file, just write `PATH=~/home/user/project:$PATH`?

Comment: Yes, add it to the bottom of the file.

Comment: I moved the file and added the line to my `~/.bashrc`, but I'm still getting the error telling me Selenium can't find the file.

Comment: Did you restart your console?

Comment: Yes, I did. (I need more characters to post a comment)

Comment: Does `echo $PATH` yield your rails folder?

Comment: Should I run that in irb? In irb console I get "NoMethodError: undefined method `echo' for main:Object".

Comment: Wait is bash just the normal terminal?

Comment: In a terminal, entering `echo $PATH` returns just an empty line.

Comment: Okay, so that's your problem. Run this line `PATH=~/home/user/project:$PATH` before you call rails.

Comment: I entered that line in bash and then tried Selenium again in irb, but I'm still getting the error, and "echo $PATH" still returns an empty line.

Comment: What does `system "echo $PATH"` in irb say?

Comment: "NoMethodError: undefined method `echo' for main:Object"

Comment: Then you didn't run what I posted.

Comment: I ran every command you posted. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: Oh I'm very sorry, you're right, I only ran part of it. I ran the full command and got back "=> true"

Comment: Ensure that `system "echo $PATH"` in erb contains `/home/user/project`. It should be  `PATH=/home/user/project:$PATH` btw, I posted the wrong path before.

Comment: Well here's the full readout: /home/user/home/user/project:/home/user/home/user/project:/home/user/home/user/project:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/.rvm/bin:/home/user/.rvm/bin:/home/user/.rvm/bin

Comment: The output you posted doesn't include `/home/user/project`

Comment: Did you run `PATH=/home/user/project:$PATH`  before starting irb without restarting the console?

Comment: Ah finally, there we go!! Yeah, I had to run that command first. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Nice. Add `PATH=/home/user/project:$PATH` to your `~/.bashrc` file and ensure that the file is loaded when you open your console, then you don't have to run the cmd manually every time.